# How does one produce this in the linear cryptanalysis of DES

Tags: cryptanalysis, des, linear-cryptanalysis

I understand how this linear approximation board below is produced,
[image]

but I can't understand how this second board is produced using the first one
[image]

and finally how the pilling-up lemma values are calculated

( o in S 12 the approx. Λ 1 = X5 XOR X7 XOR X8 XOR Y 6 has bias +1/4

o in S 22 the approx. Λ 2 = Y 6‘ XOR Z 6 XOR Z 8 has bias –1/4

o in S 32 the approx. Λ 3 = Z 6‘ XOR W6 XOR W8 has bias –1/4

o in S 34 the approx. Λ 4 = Z 1‘ 4 XOR W14 XOR W16 has bias –1/4)

Which finally leads to this:

[image]

I know this might seem like a lot but I am really stuck and all the documentations and articles I find online aren't really being much of a help, and from what I've seen here people seem really helpful on stuff like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By searching, see Matsui's paper about how many searches they did. The Hayes article is just an introduction to the field...